# Linux Shell - Certain Variables and Methods NOT appending to text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, variable

I'm having an issue getting the variables `$myname`, `$filename`, and a method that counts all the records in another file, `wc -l < hs_alt_HuRef_chr10.fa >> "$CuestaP.txt`, to append to the text file `CuestaP.txt`. Code is below I don't see why they aren't appending.

```
myname="Pablo Andres Cuesta"    #creates variable containing my name

echo "Hello my name is:"    
echo "$myname"            #Display myname
echo
echo "This program is called:"    
filename=$(basename "$0")    #Display name of file without ./
echo "$filename"

echo

echo "$myname" >> "$CuestaP.txt" #Puts myname inside text file
echo "$filename" >> "$CuestaP.txt" # Puts file name inside text file

echo "The number of records inside the file 'hs_alt_HuRef_chr10' are:"
wc -l < hs_alt_HuRef_chr10.fa
wc -l < hs_alt_HuRef_chr10.fa >> "$CuestaP.txt" #Put amount of records inside file



echo "$USER" >> "$CuestaP.txt" #Add username to text file
echo "$PWD" >> "$CuestaP.txt" #Add file location to text file


if [ -s *.fa ]; then
    # read the age from the file.
    # if the file exists and is not empty, see flags above
    echo "my *.fa file exists and has data in it" >> 
"$CuestaP.txt" 

else
echo "THIS DID NOT WORK CORRECTLY" >> "$CuestaP.txt" 

fi

echo
cat CuestaP.txt
```

My output:
    Hello my name is:
    Pablo Andres Cuesta

```
This program is called:
CuestaPOGpgm3.sh   

The number of records inside the file 'hs_alt_HuRef_chr10' are:
1842651

#myname is missing
#filename is missing
#my *.fa file exists and has data in it is missing
pcuesta    #my username went through though?
/home/pcuesta    #my pwd went through though?
```

Comment: Did you check whether the variable `CuestaP` contains the correct value? Perhaps the strings get appended to a different file than you expect. Do a `set -x` before appending the strings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the file name `$CuestaP.txt`. Either you want `$` to be literally part of the file name then you need single quotes or a backslash: `'$CuestaP.txt'`, `\$CuestaP.txt`. Or this is supposed to be a variable but then you both forgot to define it and mixed it with a literal.

Your data is in the file `.txt`

Comment: I do not want $ to literally be part of the file name, this is suppose to be a variable, I thought to append things to a text file this was the correct syntax: 

echo "$myname" >> "$CuestaP.txt" 

How come this works for $USER and not the other variables I created?

Comment: @PabloCuesta You need something like `logfile=CuestaP.txt` and then you can use `... >>"$logfile"`. I seriously doubt that this works with `$USER`. You must be more precise anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`[ -s *.fa ]` will fail if there are multiple files that have filenames that end in `.fa`.  You either test it with a single filename (`hs_alt_HuRef_chr10.fa`?) or you loop:

```
for name in *.fa; do
    if [ -s "$name" ]; then
        printf '"%s" has data in it\n' "$name"
    fi
done >>"$CuestaP.txt"
```

This, along with much of the rest of the output statements, assumes that `CuestaP` is a variable.  `$CuestaP.txt` will expand to the contents of that variable, and `.txt` will be added to the end of the value.

As far as I can see, `$CuestaP` will expand to nothing, and most of your data will go to a file named `.txt` (a hidden file in the current directory).